# Loop formula in each cell until last row

Tags: excel, vba

I want this formula to be added to each cell in column X until the very last row. Problem I'm running into is that each file will have a different number of rows. Here's what I have.

The formula works great but I need it to drop down to the last row every time.

```vb
Range("X2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DATE(LEFT(RC[1],4),MID(RC[1],5,2),RIGHT(RC[1],2))"
```

Comment: `Range("X2", Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).FormulaR1C1 = "=DATE(LEFT(RC[1],4),MID(RC[1],5,2),RIGHT(RC[1],2))"`. The linked thread explains how to find the last row. You don't need a loop to write this formula.

Comment: Thank you. It worked but now has #VALUE! in all cells. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Sounds like the data in column Y isn't what you think it is. Perhaps provide some sample data and the expected result. The formula works with sample data like `'20230321` entered in Y2.

Comment: Sure, here's a screenshot. Column Y is the unformatted date and column X is where I want the formula to be to format what's in column Y. This particular file has only 3551 rows. But this file is completed every couple of weeks with different data, so it won't always have 3551 rows. Currently the macro is adding the formula to every cell in the worksheet (row 1048576)

Comment: Actually not sure if it will let me post a screenshot

Comment: My mistake. You need to determine the last row based on column Y. So `Range("X2", Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(,-1))`